# Regular Expression with "_" only inbetween

Tags: ios, regex

I want Regulare expression which allow only _ in between strings only.Not Allow space at any place.
I had try `^[a-z]+[_]+[a-z0-9]+(?!_)$` but in this case _ is compulsory.
I want it optional.
I want out out like : `user_user12` or `user12`

Comment: The currently accepted answer will not work with Unicode letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:(?<!\d)_[a-z0-9]+)?$
```

You can group it and make it optional

Comment: what if i try user123?

Comment: in that case it will allow string start with numbers. that i don't want.

Comment: ok..it's fine.but when i write only single character then it not match.why it's happen?

Comment: if i write user123_user then it should not be allowed.

Comment: ohh yes. it's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `\w` (numbers, letters, and underscores):

```
^\w+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/tM3jL2/2

As you have mentioned earlier that it cannot start with a digit, something like this should work (also disallows repeated underscores):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/sE6tW1/2

Comment: it should not allow space.

Comment: `\w` does not match space. However, it allows `____` inside and only-`_` strings.

Comment: ohh yes...short and more understandable.